# Como encontrar o maior e menor elemento de um Array/Slice em Go?

Tags: array, golang, slice

Oi, pessoal!

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Como eu poderia encontrar o menor e maior elemento de um Array/Slice em Go? Existe alguma função da biblioteca padrão que já faça isso? Se não, poderiam me mostrar o caminho para implementar um algorítimo para resolver esse problema.

Ex:

```
numeros := []int{
    122, 992, 130, 250,
    100, 200, 202, 103,
    923, 555, 674, 893,
}
```

No meu caso eu teria que encontrar o menor e maior numero a partir de uma lista de números de cerca de *500 MB*. Se tiverem referencias de funções da biblioteca padrão para trabalhar com *`Arrays/Slices`*, por favor me mandem.

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizara função `Ints` pacote padrão `sort`. [Aqui](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints) vocẽ encontra a documentação.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer obter o maior e menor elemento, não o seu valor, poderia simplesmente fazer o `for`.

```
func MinMax(v []int) (posMin int, posMax int) {
    max, min := 0, int((^uint(0)) >> 1)

    for i, e := range v {
        if e > max {
            max, posMax = e, i
        }
        if e < min {
            min, posMin = e, i
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Sendo assim, o resultado seria:

```
slice := []int{122, 992, 130, 250, 100, 200, 202, 103, 923, 555, 674, 893}
fmt.Print(MinMax(slice))
```

> 4 1

A função tem a função de retornar a posição, não o valor, já que sua pergunta diz "encontrar o menor e maior elemento ". Enfim, o resultado da função acima, `4 1`, indicaria que `slice[4]` é o menor valor e o `slice[1]` é o maior.

Se a quantidade de dados for muito grande, creio eu que possa dividir o slice entre goroutines. Mantendo a simplicidade da comparação, bastaria que dividir `len(slice) / QuantidadeDeThreads`, então supondo que tenha 100 elementos e 4 threads teria 25 elementos para cada goroutine: a primeira compararia apenas de 0~24, a seguinte de 25~49 (...). Depois, ao fim, comparar o resultado de cada goroutine.

---

Você pode adicionar essa função como não-exportada e/ou criar um *internal package*.

---

Uma outra alternativa seria o [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/), porém apenas poderia obter o valor minimo/máximo:

```
slice := []int{122, 992, 130, 250, 100, 200, 202, 103, 923, 555, 674, 893}
sorted := sort.Ints(slice)

l := len(sorted)
if l == 0 {
    return
}

min, max := sorted[0], sorted[l - 1]
```